# What's this pipe in apt suggested packages?

Tags: debian, apt, terminology

There's a question I have about pipe `|` in the suggested packages section in `apt` command output.

For example, on my new laptop I want to install `git` so :

```
# apt install git
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  git-man liberror-perl
Paquets suggérés :
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki
  git-svn
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 mis à jour, 3 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/7 898 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 42,9 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n]
```

There is a pipe between `git-daemon-run` & `git-daemon-sysvinit`.

An other thing, if I install it with `apt install git --install-suggests`, there is now 367 new packages to install!

Do you have an explanation for these two questions?

Comment: Suggested packages are installed recursively with `--install-suggests`, i.e. suggested of suggested packages and so on. This can be a huge dependency tree. In my opinion the description in the man page is not really clear about this point.

Comment: Thank you Freddy ! I'm on your side about the man page section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `|` mean **or** .

`apt` will install `git-daemon-run` **or** `git-daemon-sysvinit`.

Debian policy : [7.1. Syntax of relationship fields](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#syntax-of-relationship-fields):

> In the Depends, Recommends, Suggests, Pre-Depends, Build-Depends, Build-Depends-Indep and Build-Depends-Arch control fields of the package, which declare dependencies on other packages, the package names listed may also **include lists of alternative package names, separated by vertical bar (pipe) symbols |**. In such a case, that part of the dependency can be satisfied by any one of the alternative packages

[git package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/git) :

> ```
> sug: git-daemon-run
>
>   fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (git-daemon service) 
>
> or git-daemon-sysvinit
>
>   fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (git-daemon service)
> ```

`man apt-get` :

```
--install-suggests
 Consider suggested packages as a dependency for installing.
```

[7.2. Binary Dependencies](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#binary-dependencies-depends-recommends-suggests-enhances-pre-depends)

> Suggests
>
> This is used to declare that one package may be more useful with one or more others. Using this field tells the packaging system and the user that the listed packages are related to this one and can perhaps enhance its usefulness, but that installing this one without them is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: As Freddy wrote, the man page is not clear about how install-suggests option will handle recursive suggestions.